# Careers: monitor search terms and notify about new matches

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I am running a long-term recruitment campaign where we want to get as many good people who match our criteria as we can. So I want to look daily for new candidates who match given search terms (either because they just joined, or because they changed their profiles).

It would be helpful to be able to register one or more searches and get notified daily about any new matches. Currently I just run the search daily and check the list against those I've seen before, which is pretty clunky.

I can imagine some slimy recruiter types using this to spam lots of people without regard to their qualifications. (I just want to read the CVs and get in touch with the small percentage who might really be suitable.) Some kind of vetting or filtering might help with this (maybe based on length and type of usage, or verified by a human at Fog Creek).

I *might* pay more for such a service.