# Is there any way to get alerts about jobs on careers site?

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I was wondering if I can get alerts about interesting jobs from the careers site and if I can show interest if I find a position that is interesting for me.

Comment: This was asked yesterday I think

Comment: Thanks, I will try to find this and post it here.

Comment: @Downvoter I did not find it, can you please post the link?

Comment: couldn't find it either, I may be wrong then...

Comment: I was thinking about this one, but it's not a duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40405

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's really not how the careers site works.

That's how the [Jobs site works](http://jobs.stackoverflow.com/default.asp). If you create a [custom search](http://jobs.stackoverflow.com/default.asp?pg=pgSearch) for jobs in your area, you can add it to your RSS feed and be notified daily through it.

Answer (score 1):

The OP's question makes sense if he is speaking from the perspective of the employer. The careers site is all about helping employers find good candidates, so having an RSS feed for custom searches would be really awesome.